# How one class is both InheritanceType.SINGL and InheritanceType.JOINED at the same time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

There are some JPA annotated class like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequence_db")
private T id;

//Some other fields with its getter & setter

}
```

And another class is:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "BASE_OFFIC")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator_col")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db" , sequenceName = "SEQ_BASE_OFFIC", allocationSize = 1)
public class BaseOffic extends BaseEntity<Integer>{

//Some other fileds here with its getter & setter methods
```

And the third class that is extended from `BaseOffic` like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("real_offic")
public class Offic extends BaseOffic {

//some other fields with its getter & setter

}
```

As you see both the Offic & BaseOffic are `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`.

With this design, every thing have worked correctly but I am forced the following task:
There is fourth class that is extended from `Offic` class with Inheritance.JOINED **while the current design as you can see in above is not changed**.

Another hand the `Offic` class is both `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` with `BaseOffic` and `Inheritance.JOINED` with fourth class that I want to create.

What is the correct syntax to do this so that both scenario are worked?

.

**EDITED:**
The fourth class is like this:

```
public class [class_name] extends Offic {
....
}
```

I want that this class is Inheritance.JOINED with the `Offic` class

Comment: JPA allows you to define the inheritance strategy at the ROOT of the inheritance tree ONLY. You cannot do what you want with JPA. The only Java persistence API supported that is JDO

Comment: How do i fix my requirement?

Comment: Fix? I've told you that you cannot do what you want. So you then have to change your expectations, and redesign how your model is designed/stored